# Apple search popularity api usage?

Tags: objective-c, app-store, itunes, apple-search-ads

I've been trying to find some documentation or usage examples for the apple search popularity api introduced in 2016.

Can anyone tell me anything about it and how I can use it?

Comment: Are you talking about Search Ads API? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppStoreSearchAdsAPIReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017495-CH26-SW1

Comment: @toma actually I'm not sure if it that, I can't see any mention of popularity?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308

Comment: Thanks, I am looking for aso / keyword figures.

Comment: I looks like this isn't possible and the only alternative is to use google keyword figures instead. A colleague contact the search api team at apple and configured that this wasn't possible.